# How to "cout" this?

Tags: c++

I am making an application just for fun 0_0 , and I have a little problem with it. The idea is to be able to run a "system" commands before the user input a number . This is what I have :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{
using namespace std;
int var1;
int var2=3600;
int var3;

cout<<"Enter the time"<<endl;
cin>>var1;
var3=(var1*var2);
system("shutdown -s -t "time_here(var3)" ")



}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're missing a semicolon.

Comment: What are you trying to "cout" that's causing trouble?

Comment: What I want is to bring var3 to the system code , that is , and I know that I miss the semicolon

Comment: I can't say for sure, but you might want [InitiateSystemShutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/aa376873(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @chris: Why did you assume Windows?

Comment: @wallyk, Oh, I didn't think Linux would have a `shutdown` command with `-s` and `-t` arguments as well. Some commands are similar or identical, but not too many that I know of. I haven't gotten around to installing Arch Linux yet :/

Comment: If you mean you want to convert `var3` to a string, try `std::string cmd = "shutdown -s -t " + std::to_string(var3); system(cmd.c_str();`

Comment: @wallyk, Looking, it doesn't seem to have a -s option. I guess I got "lucky" :p

Answer (score 4):

What you need is this I think

```
std::ostringstream out;
out << "shutdown -s -t " << var3;
system(out.str().c_str());
```

And include

```
#include<sstream>
```

Comment: And `return 0;` at the end of `main()`.

Comment: @comocomocomocomo: That's completely optional for `main`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Even if you declare it as `int main ()`?

Comment: @comocomocomocomo, `If control reaches the end
of main without encountering a return statement, the eﬀect is that of executing
return 0;` Do note that it is undefined behaviour for any other function.

Comment: @comocomocomocomo: You *must* declare the return type as `int`.  But even so, it is as chris said, as per `3.6.1/5`

Comment: @chris: Oh, I see. I'm a bit biased by Plain Old C. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
enum { N = 64 };
char buffer[ N ] = {};
snprintf( buffer, N - 1, "shutdown -s -t %d", var3 );
system( buffer );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    char input[256],buffer[256];
    cout<<"Enter the time:";
    cin >> input;

    sprintf(buffer,"shutdown -s -t %d", atoi(input) * 3600);

    system(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Passing a float to `sprintf` with a `%d` format specifier results in undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

`std::ostringstream` is a good way.
Just another option (slightly overkill)

```
std::string cmd = "shutdown -s -t " + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(var3);
system(cmd.c_str());
```

needs to include:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
```